# Active record relation condition with dynamic condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

`has_one :primary_email, class_name: 'LeadEmail', conditions: { account_id: current_account_id }, autosave: true`

Here **current_account_id** is a method which will return the current user requests account_id. Is this possible? Because current_account_id is nil while booting the app. So condtion set to nil.

Comment: `current_account_id`method is evaluated at class load. You could create a method instead.

Comment: can you give a example?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use lambda.

```
has_one :primary_email, class_name: 'LeadEmail', 
                        conditions: { account_id: -> { current_account_id } }, 
                        autosave: true
```

Comment: Is this possible in rails 3?

Comment: @KumarSiva Yes, since Ruby 1.9

Comment: `Lead.joins(:primary_email).where(id: 1).first`

TypeError: Cannot visit Proc
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/arel-3.0.3/lib/arel/visitors/visitor.rb:25:in `rescue in visit'

Comment: which version of rails you are using ?